# 80's-90's sci-fi kids movie (possibly a live-action Disney), two alien girls stranded on Earth in a ranch/farm

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find the title of a movie I saw as a kid. It is a sci-fi kids/young adults movie from the 80's, 90's, or very early 2000's about two alien girls (probably sisters, one teenager age-15-17, the other younger, maybe 10-13) who become stuck or stranded on Earth until they could be picked up by a larger/another ship. They end up at a ranch or farm (that seemed like Oregon or Montana or Colorado or some northern/mid-western state in the US) staying with a family for safety... because they do run into some trouble (I just can't remember what kind).

The girls have hair that change color from a white-ish color to a blonde/darker one, but I don't remember why it changes color. I also remember the older girl has a love interest of a boy around the same age as her who might have been the son of the family they stay with, but might not. I think she bonds with the family over the horses and other ranch work and enters a rodeo type of event or horse racing event (I'm not sure which, but I remember that does factor in somewhere).

The younger girl was kind of random comic relief and was also vaguely in the cowboy type stuff. The girls also had either some powers or technology (possibly even a critter/pet) that allowed them to cause a bit of mischief, but nothing serious (specifically the younger one).

It might have been made in Australia or Canada or it might have been a Disney knock-off or possibly even an actual Disney, but I couldn't find anything like it listed.

Comment: Not 100%, but potentially the 90's remake of Escape to Witch Mountain?

Comment: No, it's not Escape to Witch Mountain (90's version); although the feel of the movie is similar.

Comment: The show "Girl From Tomorrow" matches some of this, but not all.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229393/80s-or-90s-tv-movie-about-a-teenage-alien-girl-with-white-hair-who-stays-on-e (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

*Hyper Sapien: People from Another Star* (1986).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Sapien:_People_from_Another_Star):

> **One night, three aliens from the planet Taros — a young woman named Robyn, a girl named Tavy, and a furry three-eyed, three-armed creature named Kirbi — stow away on a spaceship headed for Earth, and land near Aladdin, Wyoming.** The next morning, the aliens befriend a rancher's son named Dirt while he's out riding fences on his motorcycle. Robyn shows off her bike-riding skills, and the quartet go to visit Dirt's grandparents. After Kirbi beats Grandpa at poker, the creature drinks a can of gasoline. Later, Kirbi keeps feeding the goats even though Grandpa wants him to feed the chickens. Grandpa then shows Kirbi how to shoot Coors cans with a gun while he complains about how much the world has changed. **Dirt forms a relationship with Robyn, learning that her hair changes color depending on exposure to sunlight** and that she's come from a moonbase and was supposed to go back to her home planet, rather than coming to Earth. Dirt tries to keep his new friends a secret from the rest of his family, but things get complicated when other aliens come looking for the missing trio, Grandpa shows Kirbi to some old folks at the General Store, and a Senator arrives at the ranch for a barbecue.

The movie is on Youtube, there are horses everywhere and the girl does stay at the end because she's in love with the ranch boy.

---

Found with the Google query `"made-for-tv" movie two alien girls ranch one stays earth` which returned [this Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/Sci-Fi-Invasion-Creeping-Galaxina-Slipstream/product-reviews/B004ZJ9VXY?pageNumber=17) of a movie set:

> Hyper sapien:People From Another Star-(Starring-Dennis Holahan-Keenan Wynn-1986-Rated PG)-Three aliens escape from a mother ship located on the Moon and seek refuge in Wyoming. Once there, they are befriended by a rancher's grandson who falls in love with the one of the alien girls. Vowing to help them in their plight, the grandson finds some difficulty when the captain of the alien mother ship arrives in search of the escapees at the same time a U.S. Senator comes to visit his grandfather's ranch.

I was actually Googling for an answer to [80's or 90's TV Movie about a teenage alien girl with white hair stays on Earth for boy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/229393); I had previously thought of browsing this site for `[story-identification] alien stay movie`, which returned this very similar question; I figured the answer would be the same, so, two birds, one stone.

Answer (score 1):

If you saw it later than you thought, you may have seen an episode (maybe a pilot?) of the 2011 series, *[Lightning Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Point)*.

> When Zoey and Kiki, two irrepressible girls from another galaxy and world called Lumina become castaways in the quiet, Australian seaside town of Lightning Point after losing their spaceship, they recruit local girl Amber to keep them undercover. But the whole town is abuzz with the sightings of U.F.O.s, the girls soon realize that they may not be the first intergalactic visitors on planet Earth. When the time comes, can they say farewell to a world as wonderful and beautiful as their own home world Lumina?

It does feature a horse, Bandit, but the main action is actually about surfing.

Comment: Honestly, it's more than a bit of a stretch, but I figure it's worth venturing.