# 80's or 90's TV Movie about a teenage alien girl with white hair, who stays on Earth for a ranch/farm boy she loves

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I don't really remember the plot but I think the a couple of alien girls (look human) crash land on Earth and are helped by human boy (18-19 ish). They get back to their ship but the older girl, with white hair, decides to stay on Earth to be with the boy.

At the beginning of the TV movie the boy wakes up and uses a ham radio and then goes to work on a ranch/farm(?).

I think it might have been one of these old Disney Sunday night movies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hyper Sapien: People from Another Star* (1986).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Sapien:_People_from_Another_Star):

> One night, three aliens from the planet Taros — a young woman named Robyn, a girl named Tavy, and a furry three-eyed, three-armed creature named Kirbi — stow away on a spaceship headed for Earth, and land near Aladdin, Wyoming. **The next morning, the aliens befriend a rancher's son named Dirt while he's out riding fences on his motorcycle. Robyn shows off her bike-riding skills**, and the quartet go to visit Dirt's grandparents. After Kirbi beats Grandpa at poker, the creature drinks a can of gasoline. Later, Kirbi keeps feeding the goats even though Grandpa wants him to feed the chickens. Grandpa then shows Kirbi how to shoot Coors cans with a gun while he complains about how much the world has changed. **Dirt forms a relationship with Robyn, learning that her hair changes color depending on exposure to sunlight** and that she's come from a moonbase and was supposed to go back to her home planet, rather than coming to Earth. Dirt tries to keep his new friends a secret from the rest of his family, but things get complicated when other aliens come looking for the missing trio, Grandpa shows Kirbi to some old folks at the General Store, and a Senator arrives at the ranch for a barbecue.

The movie is on Youtube, the girl does stay at the end because she's in love with the ranch boy.

---

I had previously browsed this site for `[story-identification] alien stay movie`, which returned the very similar [80's-90's sci-fi kids movie (possibly a live-action Disney), two alien girls stranded on Earth in a ranch/farm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149666), which had no satisfactory answer yet; I eventually found the movie with the Google query `"made-for-tv" movie two alien girls ranch one stays earth` which returned [this Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/Sci-Fi-Invasion-Creeping-Galaxina-Slipstream/product-reviews/B004ZJ9VXY?pageNumber=17) of a movie set:

> Hyper sapien:People From Another Star-(Starring-Dennis Holahan-Keenan Wynn-1986-Rated PG)-Three aliens escape from a mother ship located on the Moon and seek refuge in Wyoming. Once there, they are befriended by a rancher's grandson who falls in love with the one of the alien girls. Vowing to help them in their plight, the grandson finds some difficulty when the captain of the alien mother ship arrives in search of the escapees at the same time a U.S. Senator comes to visit his grandfather's ranch.

Comment: I'm always interested to see what kind of search terms bear fruit in questions like this.  Helps me to formulate search terms in general when I'm looking for something else.